# Tensor of inertia of two point equidistant masses on the hoop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How do you find tensor of inertia of two point equidistant masses on the hoop with respect to the axis that isn't regularly the y-axis or x-axis (so not the main axis, but we are still using regular coordinates system)?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Which plane the hoop is on?

Comment: Good question. I dont know, maybe xy. But I am asking generally anyway. I just dont understand what to do with those tensors.

Comment: I am sorry, but still I have troubles trying to picture the problem. Would you mind posting a sketch of the how the mass + hoop look like?

Comment: I have tried to draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's a slight misuse of the word *tensor* in the problem. One cannot calculate the inertia tensor with respect to an axis, what we can do is transform to another system of coordinates. So if $I$ is the inertia tensor measured in a coordinate system, and $A$ is a matrix that transforms vector according to ${\bf x'} = A {\bf x}$, then the inertia tensor after transforming the coordinate system is $I' = A I A^{T}$.

Let's apply this idea to your problem. There's two particles of mass $M$ located at the positions

$$
{\bf x}_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c} R \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ {\bf x}_2 = \left(\begin{array}{c}-R \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) = -{\bf x}_1
$$

where $R$ is the radius of the circle. The inertia tensor in this reference frame is simply

$$
I = \sum_k m_k ({\bf x}_k^T{\bf x}_k \Bbb{1} - {\bf x}_k{\bf x}_k^T)  = 2MR^2\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \tag{1}
$$

There is a couple of things you can extract from this

> Principal axis

This matrix is in diagonal form, this means that the elements of the diagonal represents the *inertia momenta* around the axis $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively. For instance the moment of inertia w.r.t the axis $x$ is $0$, which is pretty clear from your drawing, since the masses are points located along the $x$ axis

> Change of coordinates

Define the matrix

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\cos\alpha & -\sin \alpha & 0\\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \tag{2}
$$

This rotates the frame of coordinates, such that the new $x$ axis is tilted an angle $\alpha$ with respect to the old $x$ axis. The new inertia tensor in this frame is

$$
I' = A I A^T = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 R^2 M \sin^2\alpha & -2 R^2 M \sin\alpha \cos\alpha & 0 \\
 -2 R^2 M \sin\alpha \cos\alpha & 2 R^2 M \cos ^2\alpha & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 R^2 M
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: And what if the hoop has a mass too?

Comment: In that case you only need to at to Eq. (1) another term that includes the hoop 
$$
I_{\rm hoop} = \int {\rm d}^3{\bf x}~\rho ({\bf x}^T{\bf x} \Bbb{1} - {\bf x}{\bf x}^T)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The contribution of a mass ${\rm d}m$ located at $(x,y,z)$ to the mass moment of inertia tensor at the origin is

$$ {\rm d} I = \begin{bmatrix} y^2+z^2 & -x y & -y z \\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & -y z \\ -x z & - y z & x^2+y^2 \end{bmatrix} {\rm d}m $$

In your case with $(x,y,z) = \pm (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta,0)$ you have

$$ I = \begin{bmatrix} 
r^2 \sin^2 \theta & -r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta & 0 \\ -r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta & r^2 \cos^2 \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r^2 \end{bmatrix} m + \begin{bmatrix} 
r^2 \sin^2 \theta & -r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta & 0 \\ -r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta & r^2 \cos^2 \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r^2 \end{bmatrix} m$$

$$ {\rm I} = 2 m \begin{bmatrix} 
r^2 \sin^2 \theta & -r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta & 0 \\ -r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta & r^2 \cos^2 \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r^2 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: I think this is the more general answer and the simpler one, rather than deal with rotational transforms. Also if you want to add the mass of the ring it is easy as adding $$ I_{ring} = m_{ring} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \limits_0^{2 \pi} \begin{bmatrix} 
r^2 \sin^2 \theta & -r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta & 0 \\ -r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta & r^2 \cos^2 \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r^2 \end{bmatrix} {\rm d} \theta = m_{ring} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{r^2}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &  \frac{r^2}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & r^2 \end{bmatrix} $$